# How to get first 4 digits after the 0s in a decimal but keeping 0s • Python

Tags: python-3.x, floating-point, format, decimal, scientific-notation

I need the first 4 digits after the front 0s in a decimal while also keeping the 0s in the output without getting scientific notation.

Would like to take
`0.0000000000000000000000634546534`
and get
`0.00000000000000000000006345` but not
`6.345e-23`.

But would also  like to take
`231.00942353246`
and get
`231.009423`.

Thank you.

Comment: What of 2.45676, do you want 2.4567 or do you round to 2.4568?

Comment: Would be great to have an option for both, but if I had to pick 2.4567.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way using the [decimal module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html).

```
import decimal

example = 0.0000000000000000000000634546534

x = decimal.Decimal(example)
sign = x.as_tuple().sign
digits = x.as_tuple().digits
exponent = x.as_tuple().exponent

figs = 4
result = decimal.Decimal((sign, digits[:figs], len(digits)+(exponent)-figs))

precision = -1 * (len(digits) + (exponent) - figs) # for this example: -1 * (99 + (-121) - 4)
print("{:.{precision}f}".format(float(result), precision=precision))
```

Result:

`0.00000000000000000000006345`

Note that `Decimal` stores 99 digits because of floating point imprecision. The `example` variable holds a float value (due to the initializer value) that is inherently imprecise. There is no way around this, unless you are able to represent the original float value as a string, that you can use to initialize the `example` variable.

There are cases, where the 4th digit shown will be wrong, because in the floating point representation that digit is  represented as one lesser and the next digit is a 9, for example. To fix, this, we grab one more digit as well to use for rounding. This should work in most cases, as the imprecision should be within the nearest rounding threshold.

```
result = decimal.Decimal((0, digits[:figs + 1], len(digits)+(exponent)-figs-1))
```

Lastly, to handle the case where there are numbers before the decimal, we can simply store it, remove it, and re-add it:

```
whole_number_part = int(example)
example -= whole_number_part
...
result += whole_number_part
```

Altogether, we get:

```
import decimal

example = 231.00942353246

whole_number_part = int(example)

example -= whole_number_part

x = decimal.Decimal(example)
sign = x.as_tuple().sign
digits = x.as_tuple().digits
exponent = x.as_tuple().exponent

figs = 4
result = decimal.Decimal((0, digits[:figs + 1], len(digits)+(exponent)-figs-1))
result += whole_number_part

precision = -1 * (len(digits) + (exponent) - figs)
print("{:.{precision}f}".format(float(result), precision=precision))
```

Result:

`231.009423`